# Expected Value of Beta Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

What is the expected value of 1/(1+X) with X ~ Beta(2,3)?

Comment: There is a straightforward method:  find the pdf or cdf of R.V. $Y=\phi(X)$ with $\phi(x)=1/(1+x)$. I imagine you have already done this kind of exercise...

Comment: What I find funny is that WolframAlpha understands the exact same question that you posted: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What+is+the+expected+value+of+1%2F(1%2BX)+with+X+~+Beta(2,3)%3F

Answer (score 1):

The PDF of $X$ is $12x(1-x)^2$. You have to compute
$$
12\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x}x(1-x)^2dx = 12\int_0^1\left(4-3x+x^2-\frac4{1+x}\right)dx = 34 - 48 \log(2) .
$$

Comment: why the PDF of X is 12x(1-x)^2?

Comment: @karsonlauch By definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Probability_density_function

Comment: You can easily check that $\int_0^1 x^{2-1} (1-x)^{3-1} \, dx = \frac1{12}$.

Comment: Or you can use $B(2,3)=\frac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(2+3)}=\frac{1!2!}{4!}=\frac1{12}$.